# Diseño en tablayout

Tags: android, material-design

Tengo un problema y por muchos tutos que leo ahi esta, no consigo arreglarlo.
¿Que puedo hacer para que las pestañas salgan debajo de la toolbar?

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_menu1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.nav_menu1:
                fragment = new Menu1();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_menu2:
                fragment = new Menu2();
                //startActivity(new Intent(this, Menu2.class));
                break;
            case R.id.nav_menu3:
                fragment = new SimpleTabsActivity();
                //startActivity(new Intent(this, SimpleTabsActivity.class));
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }
}
```

SimpleTabsActivity.java

```
public class SimpleTabsActivity extends Fragment {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_simple_tabs, container, false);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return view;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Menu1(), "Menu 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new Menu2(), "Menu 2");
        adapter.addFragment(new Frag_Ejemplo(), "Ejemplo");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_simple_tabs.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="net.simplifiedcoding.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

¿si falta algun archivo pedirlo por favor, esto me tiene loco unas seamanas ya?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega activity_main por favor.

Comment: activity_main + app_bar_main post 1

Comment: @RafaelC.F. ya probaste cambiando a false los 3 android:fitsSystemWindows  ?

Comment: Si y no hace nada

Comment: Depronto encerrarlo todo en un relative layout, y poner la opcion below para NavigationView debajo del toolbar

Comment: @M121 no entiendo lo de Below

Answer (score 0):

yo uso uno algo asi :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/appbar"
...>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    .../>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Isaí Arellano, eso no me funciona